# SQL Server : extract multiple strings based on multiple matched value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server column with these values:

```
 Symbol1=Security1_Market1&Symbol2=Security2_Market2&Symbol3=Security3_Market3
 Symbol1=Security1_Market1&Symbol2=Security2_Market2
 Symbol1=Security1_Market1
```

What I need to achieve is to extract all values in `Symbol1`, `Symbol2` and `Symbol3`.

For example, if I have a column with value

```
"Symbol1=Security1_Market1&Symbol2=Security2_Market2&Symbol3=Security3_Market3"
```

then I need a result something like this:

[image]

If I have a column with value

```
"Symbol1=Security1_Market1&Symbol2=Security2_Market2"
```

then I need a result something like this:

[image]

Could you help me write a SQL script?

Here's my sample query:

```
SELECT  
    SUBSTRING(uriparams, CHARINDEX('=', uriparams) + 1, 
              CHARINDEX('&', uriparams) - CHARINDEX('=', uriparams) + LEN('&')) 
FROM
    [RequestLog]
```

However it is returning only 1 value.

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You'll need to post what you have tried, and which SQL flavor you're using

Comment: I think you don't understand your assignment very well. All your examples look like CGI query arguments, not SQL. (Perhaps those query strings are stored as values in your table?) I suspect what you're really asking for help on is parsing URL query strings. Search in your programming language (php, Ruby, pSQL, etc.) for "parsing URL query strings" and see if that fits what you're trying to do. Also, please don't post links to images, as they tend to break over time. Just copy the cell layout as plain text in your question, please.

Comment: Sorry, it's MS SQL. Here's my sample query:

SELECT SUBSTRING(uriparams, CHARINDEX('=', uriparams)+1
, CHARINDEX('&',uriparams) - CHARINDEX('=', uriparams) + Len('&')) 
from [RequestLog]

However it is only returning 1 value

Comment: With multiple values per row to extract this looks quite complicated unless you can use regular expressions but I am not sure what support Sql Server has for regexp functions. Maybe it's better to do this in the client code?